# BootUp-Manager no longer available?

Tags: boot, services

As I was looking for a simple GUI-based application to manage services (start, stop, enable or disable at startup), I saw Bum (BootUp Manager) as the most common recommendation.

However, it seems that it's no longer available (or at least not for Ubuntu 22.04).

What are the current alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stacer](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer/) seems rather popular, and it has a section for controlling services (the Gears icon).

[image]

It can be installed from the Universe repositories.

Comment: I've been using it since yesterday, and it is indeed quite good. Thanks for the tip!